# Отсортировать масив структур быстрой сортировкой

Tags: c, сортировка, структуры

Есть массив структур состоящий из 3-х элементов, так же есть ф-ция быстрой сортировки(так же есть в коде), но не могу понять как отсортировать массив структур по полю price.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct book
{
    char title[15];
    char author[15];
    int price;
    int pages;
};
void quicksort(int* mas, int first, int last)
{
    int mid, count;
    int f = first, l = last;
    mid = mas[(f + l) / 2]; //вычисление опорного элемента
    do
    {
        while (mas[f] < mid) f++;
        while (mas[l] > mid) l--;
        if (f <= l) //перестановка элементов
        {
            count = mas[f];
            mas[f] = mas[l];
            mas[l] = count;
            f++;
            l--;
        }
    } while (f < l);
    if (first < l) quicksort(mas, first, l);
    if (f < last) quicksort(mas, f, last);
}

int main()
{
    struct book libry[3];
    int i;
    system("chcp 1251");
    system("cls");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("Введите название %d книги : ", i + 1);
        gets_s(libry[i].title);
        printf("Введите автора %d книги : ", i + 1);
        gets_s(libry[i].author);
        printf("Введите цену %d книги : ", i + 1);
        scanf_s("%d", &libry[i].price);
        getchar();
        printf("Введіть кількість сторінок %d-ої книги : ", i + 1);
        scanf_s("%d", &libry[i].pages);
        getchar();
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("\n %d. %s ", i + 1, libry[i].author);
        printf("%s %d %d", libry[i].title, libry[i].price, libry[i].pages);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так сортировать же надо массив `book`!  `void quicksort(book* mas,...` А сравнивать поля `price`...

Comment: не совсем понял ответ, можно просто строку вызова ф-ции, и что мне нужно поменять в quicksort, исходя из моего кода

Comment: В `quicksort` вам нужно поменять заголовок, чтобы она принимала структуры, получение значения пивота, сравнение пивота с элементами массива, процедуру перестановки элементов массива местами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
void quicksort(struct book* mas, int first, int last)
{
    int f = first, l = last;
    int mid = mas[(f + l) / 2].price; //вычисление опорного элемента
    do
    {
        while (mas[f].price < mid) f++;
        while (mas[l].price > mid) l--;
        if (f <= l) //перестановка элементов
        {
            struct book count = mas[f];
            mas[f] = mas[l];
            mas[l] = count;
            f++;
            l--;
        }
    } while (f < l);
    if (first < l) quicksort(mas, first, l);
    if (f < last) quicksort(mas, f, last);
}

....

quicksort(libry,0,n);
```

См. пример полной программы [здесь](https://ideone.com/VpB7JQ).